# Div content resizing

Tags: html, wordpress, charts, resize, visualizer

I have 3 different charts inside 3 different div tags that appear and hide when specified. However, two of the charts randomly resize and i know why.
How do i fix this?
I have wordpress and using visualizer plugin for my charts. have the code in the header.php file and in the text portion of the page specific code.

Code below:

Header.php snippet -

```
<script>
    var divs = ["Daily", "Weekly", "Monthly"];
    var visibleDivId = null;
    function toggleVisibility(divId) {
      if(visibleDivId === divId) {
        visibleDivId = null;
      } else {
        visibleDivId = divId;
      }
      hideNonVisibleDivs();
    }
    function hideNonVisibleDivs() {
      var i, divId, div;
      for(i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
        divId = divs[i];
        div = document.getElementById(divId);
        if(visibleDivId === divId) {
          div.style.display = "block";
        } else {
          div.style.display = "none";
        }
      }
    }
</script>


HTML page snippet - 

<div class="inner_div"> 
<div id="Daily">[visualizer id="431"]</div>
<div id="Weekly" style="display: none;">[visualizer id="430"]</div>
<div id="Monthly" style="display: none;">[visualizer id="429"]</div>
</div>
<div class="main_div">
<div class="buttons">
<a href="#" onclick="toggleVisibility('Daily');">Daily</a> | <a href="#" onclick="toggleVisibility('Weekly');">Weekly</a> | <a href="#" onclick="toggleVisibility('Monthly');">Monthly</a>
</div>
```

Comment: please share the link of your website its not clear the resize is CSS related

Comment: www.lowfloatindex.com

clicking the daily, weekly, and monthly buttons below the charts. all the charts should, and are formatted to be the same size as the daily chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick fix is to include call `visualizer.render();` at the end of your `toggleVisibility` function:

```
function toggleVisibility(divId) {
  if(visibleDivId === divId) {
    visibleDivId = null;
  } else {
    visibleDivId = divId;
  }
  hideNonVisibleDivs();
  visualizer.render();
}
```

The problem is caused by invalid calculation of available area for divs that aren't visible at the time. Calling this method forces a re-calulcation of the svgs and ensures the right size.

Comment: Happy to help and welcome to Stack overflow. If this answer solved your issue please mark it as accepted. :)